# Magento 2.3 : File Upload issue in UI Component Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-upload, magento2.3, ui-form

I have created a form with Ui component. It contains a file field. When I upload a file it shows an error in the console
[image]

Here is my code
Ui component form

```
         <field name="ffl">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">ffl</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Licence Pdf</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ffl/ffl/fflupload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Fileupload controller

```
namespace NameSpace\Ffl\Controller\Adminhtml\Ffl;

use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Fflupload extends \NameSpace\Ffl\Controller\Adminhtml\Ffl
{    
    private $uploaderFactory;
    private $mediaDirectory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,       
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
    ) {
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;  
        parent::__construct($context, $registry);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'ffl']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['doc','pdf']);
            $path = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('fflfiles/');        ;
            $result = $uploader->save($path);

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
         }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);           
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please replace your UI Component with following code.

Change **imageUploader instead of fileUploader** in your **formElement**.

```
       <field name="ffl">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">ffl</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Licence Pdf</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!-- - Remove fileUploader -->
                    <!-- + Add imageUploader -->
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ffl/ffl/fflupload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. Is it possible to remove the "Select From Gallery" button? http://i.prntscr.com/9QBrEPg-QGuypJaV_sL39A.png

Comment: Did you get a solution? How to remove "Select From Gallery" Button?

Comment: It's not worked for me in Magento 2.3. I'm getting error: "Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $baseTmpPath" Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Other vendor(moduel-catalog , module-email , module-ui) don't override when it required then after override

To test, I first made the edit only in the file **'vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml**',

find **formElement="fileUploader"** and replace with **formElement="imageUploader"**

and it worked!

Seems to be a bug, which will be patched in Magento  2.3.1 and 2.3.0 release.